# ac-math error in emacs

Tags: emacs, latex

I installed ac-math plugin as well as auto-complete. I ac-math.el in .emacs.d/plugins/auto-complete

I put this in my .emacs

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/auto-complete/.")
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/plugins/auto-complete/ac-dict/")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)

(require 'ac-math)

(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'latex-mode) ; make auto-complete aware of latex-mode

(defun ac-latex-mode-setup () ; add ac-sources to default ac-sources
(setq ac-sources
(append '(ac-source-math-unicode ac-source-math-latex ac-source-latex-commands)
ac-sources)))

(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'ac-latex-mode-setup)
```

But I get the error "wrong type argument: integrep nil". Any help?

Comment: Did you install from ELPA? I just installed and it works great.

Comment: That should probably be [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/); it seems like [the ELPA archive](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/) doesn't have `ac-math`.

Comment: Please copy and paste error messages in their entirety. I'm pretty sure emacs didn't complain about "integrep" failing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as auto-complete-mode is concerned there is a rather out-dated homepage: http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/
If you install from there you propably do not have an up to date version like eg the one that can be found on github ( https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete ). In that repository the branch for version 1.3 (the one that is available on the homepage) was not updated in the last three years.